# Unable to seed data in ASP.NET Core in a static method due to exception 'A second operation started on this context before a previous'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to seed my database with the following code:

`Startup.Configure`:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAll")
   .UseMiddleware<JwtBearerMiddleware>()
   .UseAuthentication()
   .SeedDatabase() <= here
   .UseHttpsRedirection()
   .UseDefaultFiles()
   .UseMvc()
   .UseSpa(SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions => { });
```

`SeedDatabase` method:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder SeedDatabase(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = serviceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = serviceProvider.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
                IConfiguration configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
                ThePLeagueContext dbContext = serviceProvider.GetService<ThePLeagueContext>();
                DataBaseInitializer.SeedUsers(userManager, roleManager, configuration, dbContext);
                DataBaseInitializer.SeedTeams(dbContext);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ILogger<Program> logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
            }

            return app;
  }
```

Everything worked fine until I added `ThePLeagueContext dbContext = serviceProvider.GetService<ThePLeagueContext>();` and then the `DataBaseInitializer.SeedTeams(dbContext)`

`DataBaseInitializer.SeedTeams(dbContext)`:

```
public static async void SeedTeams(ThePLeagueContext dbContext)
{
        List<Team> teams = new List<Team>();

        // 7 because we have 7 leagues
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)...

        if (dbContext.Teams.Count() < teams.Count)
        {
            foreach (Team newTeam in teams)
            {                    
                await dbContext.Teams.AddAsync(newTeam);
                await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
}
```

When I attempt to seed the database with the above code I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.'

My database context is registered with the LifeTime of `Scoped`.

Two workarounds I found:

1. When I change my database context to `Transient` the seeding issue goes away. This however causes other issues in the application so I cannot use `Transient`
2. When I call `DatabaseInitializer.SeedTeams(dbContext)` from inside the `DatabaseInitializer.SeedUsers(...)` method, this also works, I have no clue why.

`DatabaseInitializer.SeedUsers(...)` method:

```
public async static void SeedUsers(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration, ThePLeagueContext dbContext)
{
            string[] roles = new string[] { AdminRole, SuperUserRole, UserRole };

            foreach (string role in roles)
            {
                if (!roleManager.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role))
                {
                    IdentityRole newRole = new IdentityRole
                    {
                        Name = role,
                        NormalizedName = role.ToUpper()
                    };
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(newRole);

                    if (role == AdminRole)
                    {
                        await roleManager.AddClaimAsync(newRole, new Claim(Permission, ModifyPermission));
                    }
                    else if (role == SuperUserRole)
                    {
                        await roleManager.AddClaimAsync(newRole, new Claim(Permission, RetrievePermission));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await roleManager.AddClaimAsync(newRole, new Claim(Permission, ViewPermission));
                    }
                }
            }

            ApplicationUser admin = new ApplicationUser()...

            ApplicationUser sysAdmin = new ApplicationUser()...;

            PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> password = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();

            if (!userManager.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == admin.UserName))
            {
                string hashed = password.HashPassword(admin, configuration["ThePLeagueAdminInitPassword"]);
                admin.PasswordHash = hashed;

                await userManager.CreateAsync(admin);
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(admin, AdminRole);
            }

            if (!userManager.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == sysAdmin.UserName))
            {
                string hashed = password.HashPassword(sysAdmin, configuration["ThePLeagueAdminInitPassword"]);
                sysAdmin.PasswordHash = hashed;

                await userManager.CreateAsync(sysAdmin);
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(sysAdmin, AdminRole);
            }

            SeedTeams(dbContext);

 }
```

Is there any way I can use two separate static async methods to seed the database and keep my context as scoped?

Comment: Are you awaiting SeedTeams and SeedUsers? If not they will run in parallel while sharing the DbContext.

Comment: I am not, because both of those methods are void. Should I make them return something just so I can prefix those method calls with await?

Comment: Wait! I think I should just return `Task` instead of `void` and that should solve it!

Comment: Yes, either make them async Task and await the completion, or alternately use the sync EF overloads SaveChanges (non async) if the calling method isn't async. It's not like you care about thread efficiency in a one off seeding script.

Comment: The issue is that when seeding users, I am using the built in managers, such as userManager.AddToRoleAsync and that doesnt have non Async overload

Comment: Why not create an Initialize method in DataBaseInitializer that Intializes everything? It makes for a lot cleaner code imho

Comment: So you're saying instead of having two separate method calls inside the SeedDatabase method, create a single one called DatabaseInitializer.Initialize() and then inside that method make the two method calls to seed users and see teams from there?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. But if you want you can have a seperate IdentitySeedData and a SeedDate class. You could do `public static void Populate(IServiceProvider services) { .. }` and instantiate the necessary services right there. Then all you need to do is call `DatabaseInitializer.Initialize(serviceProvider);` and then pass on the service provider to `IdentitySeedDate.Populate(serviceProvider)` and `SeedDate.Populate(serviceProvider)`

Comment: if you care to provide an answer and the async/await works I would accept as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I like to keep things ordered and seperated. Therefore I'd do something like:

```cs
public static class SeedData 
{
    public static void Populate(IServiceProvider services) 
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        if (!context.SomeDbSet.Any()) 
        {
            // ...code omitted for brevity...
        );
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

```cs
public static class IdentitySeedData 
{
    public static async Task Populate(IServiceProvider services) 
    {
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = services.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = services.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        IConfiguration configuration = services.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        ApplicationDbContext context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        if (!context.Users.Any()) 
        {
            // ...code omitted for brevity...
            await userManager.CreateAsync(sysAdmin);
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(sysAdmin, AdminRole);
        );
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And then the one to top it off:

```cs
public static class DatabaseInitializer 
{
    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider services) 
    {
         IdentitySeedData.Populate(services).Wait();
         SeedData.Populate(services);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't run the code. So if it requires some tweaking let me know. I'll make the adjustments. It's a bit time-consuming to test this out.

Comment: awesome, let me try it out. The thing I've noticed right away was when I initially get serviceProvider, the one I want to pass into the 'Initialize' method, I get it like this `IServiceProvider serviceProvider = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider;` but then inside one of the Populate methods, I cannot use `UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = serviceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();` I am forced to use `serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(UserManager<ApplicationUser>));`.Ill keep looking into it

Comment: If I also pass the `IServiceScope` everything works as expected.

Comment: Or you can just call CreateScope on the IServiceProvider? Eg. `provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();`